# How to search across a set of sheets in excel with office scripts?

Tags: excel, office-scripts

Say I have a number of sheets in online excel, I want to search for a value across a specific set of them. So if I have 15 sheets, I only want to search sheets 3 to 11 for example. I know that I can do

```
let sheet3 = workbook.getWorksheet("sheet3");
let cell_range = sheet3.findAll("String to find", { completeMatch: true });
```

The implementation I have now is that I have the sheets in an array and just loop through each one till I get a hit But is there a better way to do this rather than go one by one?

Edit: since someone asked for the current implementation

```
//I have many more sheets but I capped at 3 for brevity sake
let sheets_list = [workbook.getWorksheet("sheet3"), workbook.getWorksheet("sheet4"), workbook.getWorksheet("sheet5")];

for (let j = 0; j < sheets_list.length; j++){
let cell_range = sheets_list[j].findAll(String(search_term), { completeMatch: true });

if(cell_range)
    let cell = sheets_list[j].getRange(cell_range.getAddress());
    //.... other code
    break; //Since I just want the first occurrence anyway
}
```

Comment: Can you update your post with the current implementation you have now using arrays?

Comment: Doesn't look like there's another nice way.  What's the problem with the way you're doing it now?  If you want to cherry pick the sheets then an array seems like the only real approach and given the findAll method exists at the worksheet level, then that's just how it's been designed and you have to work with that.

Comment: @Skin I wouldn't say that theres a huge problem right now, Was just looking for a more efficient/faster way.

Comment: @BrianGonzalez I put up the implementation

Comment: @user1922979 I'm wondering if the performance issues are due to you loading all of the sheets in an array. You may see better performance if you load the sheet names in the array and only loop through them one by one. So you would update your `sheet_list` variable to something like `let sheets_list = ["sheet3", "sheet4", "sheet5"];` And then update your `cell_range` variable to something like `let cell_range = workbook.getWorksheet[sheets_list[i]).findAll(String(search_term), { completeMatch: true });`. You can try doing that and see if it helps.

Comment: @BrianGonzalez That sounds like a good idea but I get an "officescript cannot infer the data type" error. I can tell that it needs me to explicitly declare cell_range but Im not sure what to declare it to.

Comment: @user1922979 it looks like there was a typo in my original comment. I can't edit now unfortunately. But the cell_range line should be: `let cell_range = workbook.getWorksheet(sheets_list[i]).findAll(String(search_term), { completeMatch: true });`

Comment: @BrianGonzalez Ahh Yeah this definitely feels snappier now I think.  I'm still surprised there isn't a built in method but this works for now, Thanks.

Comment: @user1922979 I'm a product designer working on the office scripts project. I'm curious about your scenario and why you chose scripts. If you'd like to connect for a short discussion you can find me on LinkedIn - https://www.linkedin.com/in/jeffreydotdunn/